# How to overloading operator without using ops::Add trait?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I have some code like this:

```rust
trait MyTrait{}

struct MyStruct{}
impl MyTrait for MyStruct{}
```

i want to implement '+' operator for every struct that implement MyTrait so i tried this

```rust
impl<T: MyTrait> std::ops::Add for T
{
...
}
```

But i get the error: `` type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type ``. So now i want to implement '+' operator for every struct that implements `MyTrait` without using `std::ops::Add` trait.

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you're trying to achieve? why would you even need to redefine the Add trait?

Comment: It's not clear what the `+` will do, you can try to make a derive macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So now i want to implement '+' operator for every struct that implements `MyTrait` without using `std::ops::Add` trait.

Traits are how operator overloading is implemented in Rust (as well as most other "lifecycle" / "compiler" hooks). So you're basically asking how to implement the `+` operator without implementing the `+` operator.

The answer is that you can't.

So you can either:

- use a declarative macro to implement *both* your trait and `Add`
- not use the `+` operator

Comment: Can i re-implement ops:Add trait in my own crate and use that trait to implement ```+``` operator?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if you can create your own `Add` to manage the `+` operator? No you can't, that would be rather besides the point, *it's a compiler hook*. And if you could tell Rust to use your own custom trait to implement `+` *it would break every existing use of the operator in the language*.

Comment: Yes, i want to create my own ```Add``` trait to handler ```+``` operator since rust require both traits must be local to use blanket implement.

Answer (score 3):

This is *by design* not possible.

The reason is that Rust has the [orphan rules](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/01/14/little-orphan-impls/) which prohibit a crate (you) from implementing traits for types unless at least one of them (either the trait or the type) is defined by that crate (you).

You are trying to implement `std::op::Add` (a trait defined in another crate, `std`) for all types `T`, some of which are necessarily not defined by you (since any crate can define new types). Therefore, you violate the orphan rule.

Comment: That's the reason why i'm trying to implement '+' operator without touching ops::Add trait.

Comment: As @Masklinn points out that is just as impossible, as `+` is defined by `std::ops::Add`. Maybe define your trait to require `Add`: `trait MyTrait: std::ops::Add`. Then anyone who implements your trait will have to implement `Add` too.

Comment: Why can't I implement `Add` trait for type `T` if I add a trait bound (from my own crate). onto type `T`. Shouldn't this work? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Some other crate could implement your trait for their types too. So I wouldn't expect it to work. You might be able to argue that if your trait was private, then it should work, but I don't expect such a special case to be handled.